# habit forming artificial intelligence

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I maybe in over my head for this one, I maybe asking the wrong question but here I go. I am looking to build a habit forming AI, basically it does something once, then prioritize it based on the results to do again later or to avoid later. My main problem is I'm not sure how to store the actions. Is there any good, basic, learning AI or a guide to building one? I am using python for this, but I am just looking for basics so I can understand what they are doing.

Comment: Read Toby Segaren's "Programming Collective Intelligence".  It's a great book with Python examples.  Sounds like you want a learning neural network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conventional term for what you call "habit forming AI" is "reinforcement learning", where the estimated values of states and actions are improved by experience. [Q-learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-learning) and [SARSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SARSA) are typical examples. Search for those and you should find plenty of books, examples, tutorials, code samples etc.

Comment: Thanks, I figured I wasn't using the right term.